# http.get - Files are corrupted after download

Tags: javascript, node.js

NodeJS 0.12.2 on OSX.

I'm currently trying to download a .asar file (Electrons/Atom Shells archives) from my localhost http server (also tested with Dropbox) using http in NodeJS. However, no matter what combination I do, the archive comes down corrupted, pieces of files in other files that shouldn't be, as if the chunks are getting mixed up (if that makes any sense..)

I've also tried downloading a plain .zip file instead, from both localhost and dropbox, and run in to the same issue.

This was my last attempt I put together, and am just simply stuck. I've tried both with and without the setEncoding option. What am I doing wrong?

```
var downloadFile = function(url, dest, cb) {
  var file = fs.createWriteStream(dest);
// https when using dropbox direct links
  http.get(url, function(res) {
    res.setEncoding('binary');
    res.pipe(file);
    file.on('finish', function() {
      file.close(cb);
    });
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from you setting the encoding explicitly to binary, for example, this works just fine:

```
fs = require("fs");
http = require("http");

var downloadFile = function (url, dest, cb) {
    var file = fs.createWriteStream(dest);
    http.get(url, function (res) {
        //res.setEncoding('binary');
        res.pipe(file);
        file.on('finish', function () {
            file.close(cb);
        });
    });
};

downloadFile("http://www.sevenstring.org/forum/images/misc/ss_header_l.png", "test.png", function (err) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: I've tried both with and without and have resulted in the same issue. It's another reason why I'm very lost.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same issue. Changing encoding didn't help. I eventually figured that `gzip: true` worked.

Comment: Where are you adding this option?